# Connect node JavaScript with AngularJS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I want to create a edit profile **Form**. But my task is that my **editprofile.js** doesn't execute. But I give **editprofile.js** path in between `head` tag.

But It doesn't load the **JavaScript** file, how connect node JavaScript with AngularJS JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="payloads">
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>Payload | Edit</title>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- load jquery -->
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
          <!-- SPELLS -->
          <script src="/editprofile.js"></script>
          <!-- load angular -->
     </head>
<div id="column-content">
<img alt="payload" src="/images/logo.png">
<myspan>Payload</myspan>
</div>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div style="float:right; position:fixed ; right:0 ; bottom:0">
        <img>
    </div>

    <!-- You only need this form and the form-basic.css -->
    <form class="form-basic" method="post" action="/kyc/edit">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="fontSize">KYC</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="greyColor">Know Your Customer</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="ss-required-asterisk" aria- hidden="true">* Required</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>LegalName*</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>CNIC Number*</span>
                <input name="cnic" ng-model="cnic" required>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Father Name*<br></span>
                <input name="fatherName" ng-model="fatherName" required>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Occupation*</span>
                <input name="occupation" ng-model="occupation" required>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>NTN Number</span>
                <input name="ntn" ng-model="ntn">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="fontSize">Contact Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***editprofile.js***

> This is **JavaScript file** that show the user profile data in input text field.

```
var app = angular.module('payloads', []);
var userController = require('./controllers/userController').profileDataArray;
var profiledata = [];
profiledata = profiledata.concat(userController());
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = profiledata[0];
    $scope.cnic = profiledata[1];
    $scope.fatherName = profiledata[2];
    $scope.occupation = profiledata[3];
    $scope.ntn = profiledata[4];
});
```

Comment: Can you clean up the code a bit? very difficult to read. Best to put it in a plunker or jsfiddle.

Comment: It's quite a mess there and you have referenced AngularJS twice. Remove the old one.

Comment: I remove old one referenced AngularJS . But still problem editprofile.js cannot execute.

Comment: I clean up the code please check it out and give me the possible solution.Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're apparently trying to load NodeJS code using `require` from within client-side code?!  That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With the `require` call in `editprofile.js` you appear to be trying to load server-side NodeJS code from within your client-side UI code.  That doesn't work.

Your client and server need to be able to communicate, most likely over AJAX (e.g. using Angular's `$http` methods on the client and using `http.createServer` on the server side).